# how to get only date part from date string in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, date

i need to get in this format "2015-10-03" , but im getting like this "10/3/2015" and "10/3/2015 12:00:00 AM" both are not working in my query .because my updateddate datatype is date only

```
    Fromdate = Txtbox_AjaxCalFrom.Text.Trim();//  10/3/2015
    DateTime frmdt = Convert.ToDateTime(Fromdate);// 10/3/2015 12:00:00 AM
    ToDate = Txtbox_AjaxCalTo.Text.Trim();
    DateTime todt = Convert.ToDateTime(Fromdate);
```

i want query like this

```
updateddate between  '2015-10-03' and '2015-10-03'
```

full query

```
   gvOrders.DataSource = GetData(string.Format("select * from GoalsRoadMap where Activities='{0}' and project ='" + ProjectName + "' and updateddate between  '2015-10-03' and '2015-10-03' ", customerId));
```

Comment: your problem is actually that you need all items between  '2015-10-03' and '2015-10-03'. but it returns nothing, am I right?

Comment: yes. its returning , nothing

Comment: If you're trying to put values into SQL, *stop*. Don't do it that way at all - use parameterized SQL instead. That way you don't need to convert the value into a string at all... and you'll be avoiding SQL injection attacks, etc. (Not so much for dates, but other values...)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this:

```
DateTime frmdt = Convert.ToDateTime(fromDate); 
string frmdtString = frmdt.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
```

or at once:

`string frmdt = Convert.ToDateTime(fromDate).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");`

So your code could look like this:

```
Fromdate = Txtbox_AjaxCalFrom.Text.Trim();//  10/3/2015
string frmdt = Convert.ToDateTime(Fromdate).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
ToDate = Txtbox_AjaxCalTo.Text.Trim();
string todt = Convert.ToDateTime(todt).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");

gvOrders.DataSource = GetData(string.Format("select * from GoalsRoadMap where Activities='{0}' and project ='" + ProjectName + "' and updateddate between  '{1}' and '{2}' ", customerId, frmdt, todt  ));
```

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned by Christos you can format DateTime to universal Date string (here are examples https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zdtaw1bw(v=vs.110).aspx). But right way to create queries is to use parameters. The following sample for SqlClient, but the idea is the same for other providers.

```
var cmd=new SqlCommand("UPDATE Table1 SET field1=@value WHERE dateField=@date");
cmd.Parameters.Add("@date",SqlDbType.Date).Value=myDateTime; //myDateTime is type of DateTime
...
```

And you have an error in SQL, BETWEEN '2015-10-03' AND '2015-10-03' will return nothing. Instead try this one dateField>='2015-10-03' AND dateField<='2015-10-03'

Answer (score 1):

You could format your date string as you wish. Let that `dt` is your `DateTime` object with the value 10/3/2015 12:00:00 AM. Then you can get the string representation you want like below:

```
var formatted = dt.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
```

Comment: so use `String` instead of `var`.

Comment: `var` is a syntactic sugar. At the compile time the type of `formatted` would be declared as a `string`.

Comment: getting date in desired format, but i dont know y records not coming.@Christos

Answer (score 0):

If your SQL date items stored as date and time, not just date, then your problem will be that for items between '2015-10-03' and '2015-10-03', it returns nothing.
So you just need to add one day to your `toDate.Date` that its `Time` is 12:00:00 AM.
Something like this:

```
Fromdate = Txtbox_AjaxCalFrom.Text.Trim();//  10/3/2015
string frmdt = Convert.ToDateTime(Fromdate).Date; // 10/3/2015 12:00:00 AM
//Or
//var frmdt = DateTime.Parse(Txtbox_AjaxCalFrom.Text).Date;
ToDate = Txtbox_AjaxCalTo.Text.Trim();
string todt = Convert.ToDateTime(todt).Date.AddDays(1);// 11/3/2015 12:00:00 AM
```

now if run your query like this, it may works:

```
var items = allYourSearchItems.Where(x => x.Date >= frmdt && x.Date < todt );
```

Answer (score 0):

None of the above answer worked for me.
Sharing what worked:

```
string Text="22/11/2009";
DateTime date = DateTime.ParseExact(Text, "dd/MM/yyyy", null);              
Console.WriteLine("update date => "+date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"));
```