# How to format string "1441/10/15" exactly same to DateTime C#?

Tags: c#, datetime, model-view-controller, asp.net-mvc-5

I have string date in this format "1441/10/15" i want to change it to exact same format "1441/10/15" in datatime.

i tried to change it like this,

```
var yesy = Convert.ToDateTime(emp.datepicker);
```

but it is changing it but format is different that is `"{15/10/41 12:00:00 ص}"`

I need exact same format that is `"1441/10/15"`

thanks for your suggestion

EDITED:

I have string date "1441/10/15" how can i save it as it is in sql data base as datetime.

Comment: have you read the [docs on `DateTime` formatting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings)? it should be something like `yesy.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd")`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to get only date part from date string in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32919509/how-to-get-only-date-part-from-date-string-in-c-sharp)

Comment: Do note that the DateTime value itself doesn't *have* a format. That format only applies when you do a `.ToString()` (as is done implicitly by the debugger)

Answer (score 0):

I presume that `"{15/10/41 12:00:00 ص}"` is the output of `yesy.ToString()` in the code you didn't show to us.

Try `yesy.ToString("yyyy'/'MM'/'dd")`.

For more information about possible output format, the doc is [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings) as [Bagus Tesa](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4648586)  commented.

Comment: And use the correct Culture, which I assume is important for this value

Comment: @HansKeﬆing yes it is in `Convert.ToDateTime`, that use current culture : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.convert.todatetime?view=netcore-3.1#System_Convert_ToDateTime_System_String_. But for the `ToString(format)` part, there is no need of a culture since the format is given.

Comment: Even [the `/`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings#dateSeparator) is culture specific

Comment: @HansKeﬆing, thanks to you ! TIL

Answer (score 0):

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.Parse(emp.datepicker);
string yesy = dt.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd");
Console.WriteLine(yesy);
```

Output = "1441/10/15"

Comment: I want output in datetime format. I already has in string format